# Receive values in JSP from JS function created in other JSP

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp

I have written a code where I want the admin to be able to change the user as active or inactive through radio button. For that I am using JSP, MySQL and JS.

admin.jsp:

```
    <tr>
                <td>
                  Name:  <% out.println(firstname); %> <% out.println(lastname); %>  

                </td>
                <td>
                    <% if (flag.equals("A")){ %>

                    Active: <input type="radio" value="A" name="<% out.println(email); %>" id="<% out.println(email); %>" onchange="pageupdatecta('<% out.println(email); %>', this.value);" checked>
                    Inactive: <input type="radio" value="I" name="<% out.println(email); %>" id="<% out.println(email); %>" onchange="pageupdatecti('<% out.println(email); %>', this.value);">
                   <%
                        }else if(flag.equals("I")){%>

                    Active: <input type="radio" value="A"  name="<% out.println(email); %>" id="<% out.println(email); %>" onchange="pageupdatecta('<% out.println(email); %>', this.value);">
                    Inactive: <input type="radio" value="I" name="<% out.println(email); %>" id="<% out.println(email); %>" onchange="pageupdatecti('<% out.println(email); %>', this.value);" checked>
<%   
} %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageupdatecta(emailid, optedval) {
       location.href='changeToActive.jsp?email='+emailid+'&optedval='+o‌​ptedval; 
   } 
    function pageupdatecti(emailid, optedval) {
       location.href='changeToInactive.jsp?email='+emailid+'&optedval='+o‌​ptedval; 
   }     
</script>
```

changeToActive.jsp:

```
    try{

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
System.err.println("Driver loaded!");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/work", "root", "MyNewPass");
System.err.println("Database Connected..");

Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                       ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

stmt.executeUpdate("update assignment set flag='A' where email='"+email+"'");
                                   System.err.println("A"+email);

}
```

Can you tell me how to receive values from the function, and make my code work?

Comment: Js runs at front end while `jsp` runs at server end .

Comment: So, you have a table(no form) where there are two radio buttons and once the admin user selects any radio button the corresponding active/inactive value should be updated in DB. Also, there is no submit button. Is this right what you want?

Comment: @RohitGaikwad Yes this is right

Comment: I am not sure whether it will have any impact on you problem or not but you have given same id to both the radio fields. Can you share the url which is formed when selecting any of the radio button?

Comment: @VivekKumar http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/login.do.. Also, since it is if else condition, I don't think it should be the case...

Comment: But after clicking on any of the radio button url sould be like this:                       localhost:8080/WebApplication1/changeToActive.jsp?email=" ..."&optedval=...;

Comment: @VivekKumar No I am not getting this! I am using struts for validation from the database, is that the reason it isn't showing the needed url?

Comment: No the problem is not with Struts. The flow will go to the javascript function first and then will hit the url first. So better try to debug your code and find out whether correct URL is forming or not.

Comment: @VivekKumar I already tried debugging.. It's showing nothing in the Debugger Console!

Comment: Debug the js code on browser.

Comment: @VivekKumar Okay I did.. It's showing : SyntaxError: illegal character

Comment: Because you have given space between o and ptedval

Comment: @VivekKumar I removed the optedvalue parameter, since it was of no use in my query. Also, I debugged again, and it's showing:
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

This is what I edited:
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageupdatecta(emailid) {
      System.out.println("cta");
       location.href='http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/changeToActive.jsp?email='+emailid;
   } 
    function pageupdatecti(emailid) {
        System.out.println("cti");
       location.href='http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/changeToInactive.jsp?email='+emailid; 
    }     
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will fetch a record from assignment table of work database for id=1.
The checked status of the radio button will be decided by the existing checked status in the DB.

Here, as soon as you change the status from active to inactive OR inactive to active the changes will be reflected successfully in the database.

**index.jsp Page:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,stack.filter.JDBCConnector" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Radio Select</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Connection con = null;
String firstname = null;
String lastname = null;
String email = null;
String flag = null;
try {
    con = JDBCConnector.connect_database();
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from assignment where id=1");

    while(rs.next()){
        firstname=rs.getString(2);
        lastname=rs.getString(3);
        email=rs.getString(4);
        flag=rs.getString(5);
    }
    System.out.println(""+firstname+" "+lastname+" "+email+" "+flag);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    con.close();
}
%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
              Name:  <% out.println(firstname); %> <% out.println(lastname);          %>
        </td>
        <td> 
         <%
            if(flag.equals("A")){
                %> Active: <input type="radio" name="<%=email%>" id="r1" value="A" onclick="updateStatus()" checked="checked"/> 
                 In active: <input type="radio" name="<%=email%>" id="r2" value="I" onclick="updateStatus()"/>
                 <%
            }else if(flag.equals("I")){
                %> Active: <input type="radio" name="<%=email%>" id="r1" value="A" onclick="updateStatus()"/> 
                 In active: <input type="radio" name="<%=email%>" id="r2" value="I" onclick="updateStatus()" checked="checked"/>
                 <%
            }
         %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function updateStatus(){
            if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
                location.href='changeToActive.jsp?email='+'${email}'+'&status=A';
            }else if (document.getElementById('r2').checked) {
                location.href='changeToActive.jsp?email='+'${email}'+'&status=I';
            }       
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**changeToActive.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,stack.filter.JDBCConnector" %>  
<%
Connection con = null;
try {
    con = JDBCConnector.connect_database();
    System.err.println("Database Connected..");

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String status = request.getParameter("status");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    int i= stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE assignment SET status='"+status+"' where email='"+email+"'");
    if(i==1){
        out.println("Successfully updated the status");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    con.close();
}
%>
```

**JDBCConnector.java class:** created for centrally creating connection object in your app.

```
package stack.filter;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class JDBCConnector {        
public static Connection connect_database(){
    Connection con = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/work", "root", "root");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(con!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("Connected...");
        }
    }
    return con;
}
}
```

**Assignment Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `assignment` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`firstname` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`lastname` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

/*Data for the table `assignment` */

INSERT  INTO `assignment`(`id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`status`) VALUES (1,'rohit','gaikwad','rohitgaikwad@xyz.com','I');
```

**Note:** The id=1 primary key is hardcoded, I guess you have some logic that displays a record of assignment in your html table.

Comment: Finally my code is working.. the only editing I did in your code was I inserted the location.href directly in the onchange value, instead of calling a function for it.. because if I was using a function, it was able to identify only the last email id. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Lavina Chabra: But we should not use scriptlet on jsp. Its not at all acceptable in industry.

Comment: Looks like it's just an assignment, you can use EL/JSTL instead. I have replaced scriplet with EL.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad That seems great!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values of query parameters with:

```
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String optedval = request.getParameter("optedval");
```

Then you can use them in your sql statement.

Comment: After using this as well, I am not able to change the value to Active or Inactive through radio button in DB...

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this. You have given same id to both the radio.

```
Active: <input type="radio" value="A" name="<% out.println(email); %>" id="id1" onchange="pageupdatecta('<% out.println(email); %>');" checked>
Inactive: <input type="radio" value="I" name="<% out.println(email); %>" id="id2" onchange="pageupdatecti('<% out.println(email); %>');">


<script> 
function pageupdatecta(emailid) { 
alert('Hi');
location.href='changeToActive.jsp?email='+emailid; 
} 
function pageupdatecti(emailid) { 
alert('Hi'); 
location.href='changeToActive.jsp?email='+emailid;
} 
</script>
```

and in your servlet use `String email = request.getParameter("email");`to get the value of email variable.